# ¿Cómo obtener 2 valores llave diferentes de una lista de diccionarios y agregarlos a otra lista como subdiccionarios?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Digamos que tengo la siguiente lista de diccionarios llamada `sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info`:

```
sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info = [{'Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.00845, '24h Volume(USDT)': 1926012.715, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.03208065994500455, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.02016498625114571, 'Last Close Price': 0.01056, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT', '24h Change': 0.00605, '24h Volume(USDT)': 7340230.2529, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.040945790080738224, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03402537485582467, 'Last Close Price': 16.63, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT', '24h Change': 0.11779999999999999, '24h Volume(USDT)': 16649505.68257, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05561653860226854, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03732162458836439, 'Last Close Price': 0.2581, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT', '24h Change': 0.14821, '24h Volume(USDT)': 29672792.925, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05580029368575623, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.08076358296622625, 'Last Close Price': 6.43, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.16942000000000002, '24h Volume(USDT)': 34309469.117, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.030425963488843705, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.04462474645030439, 'Last Close Price': 9.56, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}]
```

Sí ejecuto la siguiente línea:

```
[x["0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"] for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info]
```

Obtengo el valor de cada llave llamada `"0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"` de todos los diccionarios en la lista:

```
[0.05589759007855682,
 0.058917395795956236,
 0.11376745797366504,
 0.14523057363857397,
 0.15723835541618095]
```

Sí ejecuto la siguiente línea:

```
[x["Trading Pair"] for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info]
```

Obtengo el valor de cada llave llamada `"Trading Pair"` de todos los diccionarios en la lista:

```
['TCTUSDT', 'NMRUSDT', 'STEEMUSDT', 'WINGUSDT', 'BTCSTUSDT']
```

Ahora, la duda que tengo es cómo podría obtener los valores de ambas llaves de manera que terminen siendo presentadas como la siguiente lista de diccionarios?

```
[{Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682},
{'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236},
{'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504},
{'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397},
{'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución:

```
salida = []
for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info:
    nuevo = {"Trading Pair": x["Trading Pair"],
             "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": x["0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"]
             }
    salida.append(nuevo)
```

El `for` recorre los diccionarios de la lista original. Por cada diccionario se crea uno nuevo con las dos llaves de interes y sus respectivos valores.

Este diccionario se agrega a la lista de salida.

**Demo**

```
sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info = [
    {'Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.00845, '24h Volume(USDT)': 1926012.715,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.03208065994500455,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.02016498625114571, 'Last Close Price': 0.01056,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT', '24h Change': 0.00605, '24h Volume(USDT)': 7340230.2529,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.040945790080738224,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03402537485582467, 'Last Close Price': 16.63,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT', '24h Change': 0.11779999999999999, '24h Volume(USDT)': 16649505.68257,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05561653860226854,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03732162458836439, 'Last Close Price': 0.2581,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT', '24h Change': 0.14821, '24h Volume(USDT)': 29672792.925,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05580029368575623,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.08076358296622625, 'Last Close Price': 6.43,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.16942000000000002, '24h Volume(USDT)': 34309469.117,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.030425963488843705,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.04462474645030439, 'Last Close Price': 9.56,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}]

salida = []
for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info:
    nuevo = {"Trading Pair": x["Trading Pair"],
             "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": x["0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"]
             }
    salida.append(nuevo)

for x in salida:
    print(x)
```

produce:

```
{'Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT', '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682}
{'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT', '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236}
{'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT', '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504}
{'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT', '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397}
{'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT', '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Tío Moe!

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una versión de [la respuesta de Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/545720/158880) que utiliza una función para evitar escribir código repetitivo y poco claro:

```
def extract_items(dct, *keys):
    return {key:dct[key] for key in keys}

# Esta lista de diccionarios viene de la respuesta de Candid Moe
sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info = [
    {'Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.00845, '24h Volume(USDT)': 1926012.715,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.03208065994500455,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.02016498625114571, 'Last Close Price': 0.01056,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT', '24h Change': 0.00605, '24h Volume(USDT)': 7340230.2529,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.040945790080738224,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03402537485582467, 'Last Close Price': 16.63,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT', '24h Change': 0.11779999999999999, '24h Volume(USDT)': 16649505.68257,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05561653860226854,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03732162458836439, 'Last Close Price': 0.2581,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT', '24h Change': 0.14821, '24h Volume(USDT)': 29672792.925,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05580029368575623,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.08076358296622625, 'Last Close Price': 6.43,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')},
    {'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.16942000000000002, '24h Volume(USDT)': 34309469.117,
     '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.030425963488843705,
     '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.04462474645030439, 'Last Close Price': 9.56,
     'Last Start Date UTC': ('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}]

print([extract_items(x, "Trading Pair", "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility") for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info])
```

La función extract_items toma un primer argumento que sería el diccionario, e infinitos otros argumentos que serían las claves a las que se quiere acceder, recorre las claves, creando un nuevo diccionario donde se "copia" el item del diccionario original.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución, trataré de siempre crear funciones para hacer ciertos procesos particulares 

Comment: De nada Noah c: